# MongoDB schema design, can I embed and reference data at the same time?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, schema

I am new to MongoDB, I have read many suggestions regarding the pros and cons of embedding and referencing documents, but could not find any example of using both. For example, if I want to build a friends list, and only want to see the name and the profile picture every time someone wants to see their friends list, can I embed these data along with the id of the friend objects? These data are duplicated, but it would save the number of queries required.

```
person = {
  _id: '123abv',
  name: 'bob',
  profilePic: '...',
  ...other props,
  friends: [
    {
      _id: '124sdf',
      name: 'tom',
      profilePic: '...'
    },
    ...other friends
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB schema design depends almost every time on the queries that your application is going to do in order to improve speed.
The main downside of duplicating information is the space needed for it and the extra effort needed to update the embedded documents as well as the documents itself.

My suggestion would be:

- If your application is mainly used for querying the documents, it's hardly updated and space is not a problem (which nowadays tends not to be), you could duplicate the information in order to improve speed. It would help you to avoid complex aggregations and find queries in your database.
- If your application suffers a lot of updates and has relationship between documents, first of all, I would suggest checking for a relational database because they have better performance while solving the relations. If MongoDB is mandatory, probably I would referenciate the document without duplicating the information leaving behind some performance. Anyway, performance could always be improved implementing Sharding or indexes in your database.

Answer (score 0):

This is called the [**Extended Reference Pattern**](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-extended-reference-pattern) in MongoDB. It is the recommended pattern for when you need frequent access to a small part of a reference document. Just consider the tolerance you have for staleness before you use it.